# jQuery.getJSON callback does not fire in IE7

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-7, jsonlint

A **valid** JSON*, returned with correct HTTP headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json; charset=
```

Works in Chrome/FF, and IE7 is refusing to parse it.

Where do I look for clues?

```
 $.getJSON(url, null, function(data){ alert(data); /* never fires in IE7 */ });
```

*(valid according to [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) )*

Comment: Can you post some of your code from the getJSON callback and some of the json that is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL at another domain?  IE's XDomainRequest was added in IE8, so you won't be able to make cross-domain ajax requests in IE7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Use JSONP instead.